# Using node.js http module

Tags: node.js, http, coffeescript

I can't seem to get a simple http request to work with node.js. The following code simply hangs without logging anything or printing any errors.

```
http = require 'http'

callback = (response) ->
  console.log 'callback'
  str = ''

  # another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on 'data', (chunk) ->
    console.log 'data'
    str += chunk

  # the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on 'end', ->
    console.log str

http.get 'http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json', callback
```

Generated javascript:

```
// Generated by CoffeeScript 1.10.0
(function() {
  var callback, http;

  http = require('http');

  callback = function(response) {
    var str;
    console.log('callback');
    str = '';
    response.on('data', function(chunk) {
      console.log('data');
      return str += chunk;
    });
    return response.on('end', function() {
      return console.log(str);
    });
  };

  http.get('http://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json', callback);

}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your existing code seems to work fine with other URLs. That URL in particular doesn't seem to work over HTTP, at least it hangs when I use `curl`. Loading it in the browser does seem to return a 307 redirect to the HTTPS version, so I'm not sure why it's not responding to `curl` or your code.

Regardless, you probably want to use the HTTPS URL anyway, so just change your code to do that:

```
https = require 'https'

callback = (response) ->
  console.log 'callback'
  str = ''

  # another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on 'data', (chunk) ->
    console.log 'data'
    str += chunk

  # the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on 'end', ->
    console.log str

https.get 'https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json', callback
```

Answer (score 0):

Try use lib that support both http and https, like,  'request' or 'request-promise'.

The below example works fine,

```
var request = require('request');
request('https://www.xxxxx.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body);
  }
})
```

More information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request